# method invocation getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() may produce null pointer exception in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

"Here is my code below and link of image"

```
MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();


    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.guide_frame_container, newFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

[image]

Comment: post error you get in Logcat

Comment: where is the newFragment  initialised??? And why are you adding null to your backStack ??

Comment: ok, and what is your question?

Comment: MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
this is my initialisation of newfragment.

Comment: its clearly seems like warning shown in android studio. this not error just warning.  First run your app if you get error then post your logcat here

Comment: That is just a warning. You can check for null to `getActivity()` prior to that sentence. Or use `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
    .replace(R.id.guide_frame_container, newFragment)
    .addToBackStack("MyFragment")
    .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Android Studio warning, no error. But you should care about it!

`getActivity()` is not guaranteed to return always an activity. For instance when the fragment is created, but not yet attached, i.e. `getActivity()` will ALWAYS return null when called in the constructor. Same for `getSupportFragmentManager()` which requires the fragement to be attached as well, to get its corresponding fragment host.

So, you have to ensure, that you either call those function only in a well known context, where the fragment is guaranteed to be attached (like in the `onAttached()` function) or you have to wrap the calls in null checks

Additionally, it is absolutely unclear, where you call those functions. I assume, you try to call those inside of the `static Fragment newInstance()` function which shall create the fragment for you. However, you should never try to attach the fragment there. It should be done by the host activity.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this method is deprecated but still, this line of code removes that warning. 
override onAttach in your fragment. Then in the above take an instance of Activity class like this.

```
private Activity mActivity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // your code
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}
```

Now instead of getActivity() use mActivity

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent this warning, I typically use this pattern:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity(), "<some message describing what went wrong>")
```

This will throw an exception that gives you a better idea of what just happened.

Here is a longer example:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity(), "Activity not available in traffic control fragment")
            .getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(() -> {
                setRepeatButtonText(getView());
                setSwitchButtonState(switchButton);
                if (mainActivity.getTabIndex() == 2 && getFragmentManager()!=null && getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
                    mainActivity.setDateOnABar(getString(org.brahmakumaris.beezone.R.string.traffic_control));
                }
                else if (mainActivity.getTabIndex() == 2 && getFragmentManager()!=null && getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1){
                    mainActivity.setDailyOnABar(getString(org.brahmakumaris.beezone.R.string.traffic_control), false);
                }
            });
```